# srtp gives error on make command ubuntu

Tags: asterisk

While building Asterisk, `make && make install` command showing error:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://srtp.sourceforge.net/srtp-1.4.2.tgz
tar zxvf srtp-1.4.2.tgz
cd /usr/local/src/srtp
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=/usr/local/lib
make && make install
```

**ERROR :**

```
root@odooenterprise:/usr/local/src/srtp# sudo make
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Icrypto/include -I./include -I./crypto/include  -fPIC -L. crypto/test/aes_calc.c -o crypto/test/aes_calc -lsrtp
In file included from crypto/test/aes_calc.c:21:0:
crypto/include/aes.h:63:1: warning: inline function ‘aes_expand_decryption_key’ declared but never defined
 aes_expand_decryption_key(const v128_t *key,
 ^
crypto/include/aes.h:59:1: warning: inline function ‘aes_expand_encryption_key’ declared but never defined
 aes_expand_encryption_key(const v128_t *key,
 ^
/tmp/ccwdFuqZ.o: In function `main':
aes_calc.c:(.text+0x2a9): undefined reference to `aes_expand_encryption_key'
./libsrtp.a(datatypes.o): In function `is_hex_string':
datatypes.c:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `hex_char_to_nibble'
./libsrtp.a(datatypes.o): In function `hex_string_to_octet_string':
datatypes.c:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `hex_char_to_nibble'
datatypes.c:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `hex_char_to_nibble'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'crypto/test/aes_calc' failed
make: *** [crypto/test/aes_calc] Error 1
```

Comment: Sound's like that function `aes_expand_decryption_key` is declared somewhere else already... check eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681442/function-declared-static-but-never-defined

Comment: Perform a `grep -IR aes_expand_decryption_key` and then provide the output in the question.